# how to add custom view on UITableViewCell programatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

**UPD Resolved - see edited question below**

Trying to add a custom view (button, to be more specific) to a custom subclass of UITableViewCell but unable to see any layout results on iOS 10.1 on the device. Did not see any changes on the layout, and tried to just fill the cell with a custom view with the red background but failed to achieve this result as well.

```
import UIKit

class Save: UITableViewCell {

    let containerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        return view
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    func setupViews() {
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    }

}
```

What I tried besides that: using plain addSubiew and constraint to the `self` anchors of the cell, and add to contentView in `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` but both approaches did nothing, the cell appears but it is empty.

**UPD**
attaching the TableView initiation code for the reference

```
class SettingsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    let settings = [
        "setting1",
        "setting2",
        "setting3",
        "setting4",
        "setting5",
        "setting6",
        "setting7"
    ]


    let overlay: UIView = {
        var view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .gray
        view.alpha = 0.3
        view.isHidden = true
        return view
    }()



    let tableView: UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .grouped)
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "commonCell")
        tableView.register(Save.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "btnCell")
        tableView.register(Switcher.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "switcherCell")
        tableView.headerView(forSection: 0)?.textLabel?.text = "settings of app"
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.allowsSelection = false
        return tableView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupViews()
    }

    func setupViews() {
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(tableView)

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true


    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        tabBarController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = []
        tabBarController?.navigationItem.title = "settings"
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return settings.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "settings"
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "commonCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = settings[indexPath.row]
        if(indexPath.row == 6) {
            cell.textLabel?.text = ""
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "btnCell", for: indexPath)
        }
        return cell
    }


}
```

**RESOLVED**

in addition to Sh_Khan answer, it was required to set

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 65
```

on the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either implement

```
heightForRowAt
```

Or add

```
containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:200).isActive = true
```

---

Also add any subview to `contentView`

```
contentView.addSubview(containerView)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([ 
    containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
    containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
    containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
    containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
    containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:200)
])
```

Comment: Would this be `self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` another issue in the code? I think it would ignore the height constraints.

Comment: Sh_Khan, tried both ways, but for some reason they did not work, suspecting a problem in declaring a table, attaching code, I would be much appreciated to get any help or hint

Comment: thank you, with your help, managed to resolve by settings `rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and fixed `estimatedRowHeight = 65`

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like it's anything wrong with the code in your cell class in my eyes. Can you please add your tableviewcode?

Comment: I saw that you casted         view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
 twice. try removing that one inside setupViews()

Comment: I tried running your Code (except the class Switch) and it works when removing the autordranslte inside setupViews for me. I hope does that does the trick!